# Scrollviewer of a ListBox is Visible according to the count of Items

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

I have a **ListBox** with its **DataTemplate** defined. The **ItemSource** (ListBoxItem) for the **ListBox** is provided via the ViewModel.

I want the scroll viewer of the ListBox to appear when the count of the items is more than 5. I would be glad if someone can assist me.

Here is a part of my code:

```
<ListBox  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0"   
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Parts, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedIndex="{Binding CurrentPartIndex}"                       
                    Height="115" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrush}}">                   
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding CurrentLabel, Mode=OneWay}" MinWidth="150" Width="auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding ItemNumber, Mode=OneWay}" MinWidth="50" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding Cut, Mode=OneWay}" MinWidth="50" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="3" Content="{Binding Material, Mode=OneWay}" MinWidth="100" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>                           
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Try setting Horizontal & Vertical ScollbarVisibility to Auto. And play around with the Control Height so that 5 items dont cause the scrollbar to appear.

Comment: I would implement an IValueConverter for the ScrollViewer that converts the item count to a HorizontalalScrollBarVisibility, returning Visible for values > 5, Hidden otherwise.

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava I tried that way but that's not a general way since it's resolution dependent. Changes in different PCs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a value converter so the number of items in the **ListBox** controls the visibility of the **ScrollViewer**.

The converter:

```
public class CountToVisibility : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((int)value > 5)
            return ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
        else
            return ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:CountToVisibility x:Key="ctv"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

...

```
<ListBox  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0"   
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Parts, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedIndex="{Binding CurrentPartIndex}"                       
                Height="115" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrush}}"
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{Binding Path=Parts.Count,Converter={StaticResource ctv}}">                   
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding CurrentLabel, Mode=OneWay}" MinWidth="150" Width="auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding ItemNumber, Mode=OneWay}" MinWidth="50" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding Cut, Mode=OneWay}" MinWidth="50" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="3" Content="{Binding Material, Mode=OneWay}" MinWidth="100" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>                           
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```